# Cumulative sum - how to do that in Beam (Python) in a batch process over a time series?

Tags: python, time-series, apache-beam, batch-processing, cumulative-sum

I want to create a cumulative sum over a time series in a bounded batch processing in Apache beam with the Python API. What you can do is to write a cummulative sum with a stateful DoFn, but the problem you would still face is that you cannot handle it this way when the data in unordered, which is the case in a PCollection. Is there a way to make the cumulative sum over time in a batch process? This is what i did (whithout order):

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import TimeDomain
from apache_beam.transforms.userstate import ReadModifyWriteStateSpec, TimerSpec, CombiningValueStateSpec
from apache_beam.transforms.window import FixedWindows, GlobalWindows


class TimestampedSumAccumulator(beam.DoFn):
    SUM_STATE = 'sum'

    def process(
        self, element,
        timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam,
        sum_state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(ReadModifyWriteStateSpec(SUM_STATE, beam.coders.FloatCoder()))
    ):
        sum_value = sum_state.read() or 0.0
        # print(element)
        sum_value += element[1]
        sum_state.write(sum_value)
        yield beam.transforms.window.TimestampedValue(sum_value, timestamp)


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    sums = (p
        | 'Create' >> beam.Create([
            (3.1, 3),
            (1.5, 1),
            (4.2, 4),
            (5.4, 5),
            (2.3, 2)
        ])
        | 'AddTimestamps' >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.transforms.window.TimestampedValue(x[0], x[1]))
        | 'AddKeys' >> beam.Map(lambda x: ('sum_key', x))
        | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(10))
        | 'Accumulate' >> beam.ParDo(TimestampedSumAccumulator())
        | 'Print' >> beam.Map(print))
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: As you said: beam does not process data necessarily in order. I assume you require the cumulative sum for later analysis (possible outside of dataflow)? Why not calculate the sum as you have described in your example, but additionally add the respective timestamp (timestamp, cumulative_sum)? That way you can order it later, even if it is shuffled within your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

use CombinePerKey, which allows you to combine values of the same key in a PCollection. Then you can create a key-value pair where the key is a constant, and the value is a tuple containing the timestamp and the value you want to accumulate. Then use CombinePerKey to combine the values for each key, and add them up to get the cumulative sum.

```
import apache_beam as beam

class CumulativeSumFn(beam.CombineFn):
    def create_accumulator(self):
        return 0.0

    def add_input(self, accumulator, input):
        timestamp, value = input
        return accumulator + value

    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
        return sum(accumulators)

    def extract_output(self, accumulator):
        return accumulator

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    sums = (p
        | 'Create' >> beam.Create([
            (3.1, 3),
            (1.5, 1),
            (4.2, 4),
            (5.4, 5),
            (2.3, 2)
        ])
        | 'AddTimestamps' >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.transforms.window.TimestampedValue(x[1], x[0]))
        | 'AddKeys' >> beam.Map(lambda x: ('sum_key', (x.timestamp, x.value)))
        | 'CombinePerKey' >> beam.CombinePerKey(CumulativeSumFn())
        | 'Print' >> beam.Map(print))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. When i run your code it raise an exception. Anyways i feel that your solution just gives a cum of everything (16.5) and does not give the cumsum in every timestamp :(